# How do you get the list of objects on which a method can be called?

Tags: ruby

Is there a method like `+.method` which can give a list of classes on which `+` can be called upon?

Comment: No, not really - especially `Float#+` is different than `Integer#+` and both are different than `Array#+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hack which actually guarantees nothing, but you might want to try:

```
▶ ObjectSpace.each_object.select { |obj| 
    Class === obj && obj.instance_methods.include?(:+) 
  }
#=> [
#  [0] Complex < Numeric,
#  [1] Rational < Numeric,
#  [2] Time < Object,
#  [3] Array < Object,
#  [4] Bignum < Integer,
#  [5] Float < Numeric,
#  [6] Fixnum < Integer,
#  [7] String < Object,
#  [8] Pathname < Object,
#  [9] CodeRay::Tokens < Array
```

Comment: While this probably suffices for the OP, it should be noted that this just shows which classes actually have the `+` method. It does not guarantee the same functionality!

Comment: @David I definitely noted it with “actually guarantees nothing” preceeding the snippet :)

Comment: I know that their functionality differs based on which classes they are used with. But I just wanted to see which classes any method can be used upon.